# Using Bootstrap Grid How to implement product carousel

Tags: angularjs

using angularJs 1.6 and bootsrap3 grid i want to implement  product card carousel slider without using any third party library is it possible please help me if anyone know friends

```
  Left arrow <---    product-1-div    product-2-div    product-3  -->Rarrow
```

if i click right arrow next 3 product column should appear please friends help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.products = []
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    $scope.products.push({
      name: 'Product' + i
    })
})
```

```css
.col-xs-4 {
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: 2px solid #5162d2;
}

li {  
  background-color: #5162d2 !important
}
```

```html
<link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script data-require="jquery@2.0.0" data-semver="2.0.0" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script data-require="angularjs@1.6.2" data-semver="1.6.2" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.js"></script>


<body ng-app='app' ng-controller='ctrl'>
  <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="{{$index/3}}" ng-class="{active:$first}" ng-repeat='item in products' ng-if='$index%3==0'></li>
    </ol>
    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item" ng-class='{active:$first}' ng-repeat='item in products' ng-if='$index%3==0'>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-4" ng-repeat='x in [0, 1, 2]'>{{products[$parent.$index+x].name}}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: can you tell how the carousel are showing the grids in order of 1 2 3 and so

Comment: @ChellappanV, I simply create common carousel, the same as bootstrap's example, where each slide starts from _third_ product: `ng-if='$index%3==0'` and contains this product and next two: `ng-repeat='x in [0, 1, 2]'` with `{{products[$parent.$index+x].name}}`.